# About the category of chain complexes and Grothendieck categories.

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Given an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ the category of chain complexes over $\mathcal{A}$ is again an abelian category. If $\mathcal{A}$ is a Grothendieck category then the category of chain complexes over $\mathcal{A}$ is a Grothendieck category? In praticular, for a ring $R$ with unitary and the category of its left unitary modules, does this hold?

Feel free to retag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is stated e.g. on page 3 of [Hovey: Model category structures on chain complexes of sheaves](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/0366/sheaves.pdf).

Comment: what is the generators of Ch(Mod-R)?

Comment: For generators of $\mathbf{Ch(Mod_R)}$, see page 3 of the link provided in this answer.